# jquery datatable add class to row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable which when I click on a row, it highlights the row. I want to save the row index and use it to re-highlight that row when the page is reloaded.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                    "ajax": "DataQueries/FetchOpenJobs.asp",
                    stateSave: true,
                    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
                    "iDisplayLength": 25,
                    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                    columnDefs: [
                        {"visible": false, "targets": [2,3]},
                        {"type": 'date-uk', "targets": [1,9,10] },
                        {"type": 'title-string', "targets": [11] }
                    ],
                } );
```

I am able to get the row index using the below:

```
var selectedRowIndex = table.row(this).index();
```

However, I am unsure as to how to re-highlight using the row index.

Comment: Are you saving it to server side anywhere? or just on client browser?

Answer (score 2):

I think this question deserves a more thorough example.

I would save the selected `id`('s) in the `localStorage` as an stringified array. When the page is (re)loaded then retrieve the array and if it contains any stored indexes, highlight the corresponding rows. Below a code example in explanatory order :

Sample code of highlightning rows when they are clicked :

```
$('#example').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    processSelected(table.row(this).index(), $(this).hasClass('highlight'));
});
```

Basic code for maintaining an array of highlighted row indexes in the localStorage :

```
function processSelected(id, selected) {
   if (selected) {
      selectedRows.push(id);
   } else {
      selectedRows.splice(selectedRows.indexOf(id), 1);
   }
   localStorage.setItem('selectedRows', JSON.stringify(selectedRows));
}
```

When the page is loaded, retrieve the array from localStorage :

```
var selectedRows = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedRows'));
```

Finally, re-highlight stored row indexes when the dataTable is initialised :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete : function() {
       if (!Array.isArray(selectedRows)) {
          //selectedRows does not exists in localStorage or is messed up
          selectedRows = [];
       } else {   
          var _table = this.api(); 
          selectedRows.forEach(function(index) {
             //for some reason to$() doesnt work here 
             $(_table.row(index).node()).addClass('highlight');
          })
       }    
   }
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/f3ghvz4n/**

Try the demo, highlight some rows and then reload the page. Notice that this works on a paginated dataTable as well!

---

**Update**. When you are using a AJAX datasrc reloaded each 30 secs, I think you could skip the `initComplete` and just rely on the `draw.dt` event :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example').on('draw.dt', function() {
   if (!Array.isArray(selectedRows)) {
      selectedRows = [];
   } else {   
      selectedRows.forEach(function(index) {
         $(table.row(index).node()).addClass('highlight');
      })
   }   
})
```

Completely untested, but cannot see why it shouldnt work.

Comment: This is great. It actually does hold the highlight but I still have a small problem. I used table.ajax.reload() function to reload the table every 30 secs. At that point, I lose the highlight. But if I refresh the entire page, The highlight comes back on again (until the next ajax,reload() kicks in)

Comment: @Saj, place the code inside `initComplete` in a function you can call after each `ajax.reload()`.

Comment: Can I call it this way?  

    table.ajax.reload( function() {
      if (!Array.isArray(selectedRows)) {
        selectedRows = []; 
       } else {
        var _table = this.api();
        selectedRows.forEach(function(index) {
         $(_table.row(index).node()).addClass('selected'); 
        });
       }
     });

Comment: @Saj, see update - it was something like this I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#id tbody > tr').eq(rowindex)
```

or

```
$('#id tbody > tr').eq(rowindex).children().addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: tried that but no luck. When the page reloads, it still drops off the highlight

Comment: Put this code in [`"fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {// code here}});`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete)

Comment: I have added that to the initComplete but still no luck

Comment: what does `$('#id tbody > tr').eq(rowindex).children()` return does it return an `object`  or `null`??

Comment: it returns an [object Object]

Comment: does it return the desired `row` ?

Comment: it does not. I am revising the code but so far not looking good